# Why did my question get downvoted?

Tags: discussion, support

Well I am a beginner to web designing and I asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985133/how-to-connect-a-html-css-js-webpage-to-a-server-and-database and instead of getting some help I got downvoted, can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: 1. It wasn't really a question. 2. It asked for an of-site resource

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I was wondering if someone could provide me with some resource where I can understand how to link a webpage (made with html/css/js) to a database and a server ( preferably jsp).

You are asking people to recommend a tutorial/off-site resource. [This is offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for these reasons:

- Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.
- Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @user3335993: make sure to read through [all the guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help) so you can avoid this in the future.